# 6-core Sandy Bridge-E vs. 4-core Ivy Bridge

Tags: intel-core-i7, multi-core, sandy-bridge, ivy-bridge

I am currently choosing between Intel Core i7-3770 (quad, Ivy) and Intel Core i7-3930K (6 cores, Sandy Bridge-E). This machine will be used for both work (Adobe, Autodesk software, graphic and coding-related) and gaming.

Even if some applications I will use are capable to utilize all 6 cores at once, is it worth preferring Sandy Bridge-E to newer Ivy Bridge? Games aren't and probably will perform better on Ivy, won't they? 6-core is also twice as expensive as a quad Ivy.

Comment: Ivy Bridge introduced PCIe 3.0 support, Sandy bridge has only 2.0 - that is the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed improvement you can get from PCIe 3.0 compared to a PCIe 2.0 is currently not large. Furthermore it only matters if you copy e.g. textures or other data onto the video card or if the on-card is not large enough to hold all data.

Lets compare the processors:

[Sandy bridge i7-3930K](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/63697)

- 6 cores
- 12 MB cache
- frequency 3.2 - 3.8 GHz
- TDP 130W

[Ivy Bridge i7-3770](http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/)

- 4 cores
- 8 MB cache
- frequency 3.4 - 3.9 GHz
- TDP 77 Watt

AFAIR Ivy bridge is up to 5% faster with the same frequency.

Conclusion: If your software is capable to utilize all six cores the Sandy Bridge should be faster - otherwise if your software often can utilize 4 or less cores the Ivy Bridge should be faster.

Furthermore the Sandy bridge takes much more power and is therefore louder - only matters if we are talking about a desktop system.